# why does getting vulkan extensions from a method fail vulkan instance creation?

Tags: c++, sdl-2, vulkan

I am following the vulkan-tutorial.com tutorial and im on the validation layers step. In the tutorial Alexander Overvoorde the author moved the gathering of available extensions for instance creation to its own function.

```
std::vector<const char*> getRequiredExtensions()
```

Previously i had gathered that info a little differently because i am using SDL2 instead of glfw, but my program ran with instance creation and no validation errors. Problem is when i moved the code to this function i can no longer get instance creation.

this worked fine:

```
unsigned int extensionCount = 0;
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(NULL, &extensionCount, NULL);
std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> extensionProperties(extensionCount);
vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(NULL, &extensionCount, extensionProperties.data());
std::vector<const char*> extensionNames;
std::cout << "available extensions:" << std::endl;
int i = 0;
while (i < extensionCount) {
    extensionNames.push_back(extensionProperties[i].extensionName);
    std::cout << extensionNames[i] << std::endl;
    i++;
}
if (enableValidationLayers) {
    extensionNames.push_back(VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME);
}*/
createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = extensionCount;
createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensionNames.data();
```

but this failed even though the function uses the exact same code and returns extensionNames, i then use it like this:

```
std::vector<const char*> extensionNames = getRequiredExtensions();
createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensionNames.size());
createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensionNames.data();
```

So why doesn't this work? I have a formally taught background of java but have coded in c++ for a year, so it is possibly like a syntax error or pointer that i am sending wrong. Additionally

```
reateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(getRequiredExtensions().size());
```

works just fine so the returned vector is of the correct size: 5 i believe because i have 4 extensions plus the debug one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation at Khronos.org](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkExtensionProperties.html), `VkExtensionProperties` looks like this:

```
typedef struct VkExtensionProperties {
    char        extensionName[VK_MAX_EXTENSION_NAME_SIZE];
    uint32_t    specVersion;
} VkExtensionProperties;
```

... so on this line:

```
extensionNames.push_back(extensionProperties[i].extensionName);
```

... what you're storing into `extensionNames` are pointers to arrays that live in `extensionProperties`, which is local to your function. When you return from the function, all of the arrays are destructed along with `extensionProperties`, and all of your pointers are now dangling.
What you get then is undefined behaviour when Vulkan tries to use these dead pointers.

Comment: can you advise the best way for me to get past this? will using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const char>> getRequiredExtensions()` work? because i cant get `createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensionNames.data();` to take `std::vector<<std::shared_ptr<const char>>`

Comment: iv tried using a shared ptr and it will not work, i really want to keep the extensionProperties local to the function

Comment: @MatthewBuchanan in this case, I'd say don't sweat it and make your API clean as a priority. Return a `std::vector<std::string>`, and in the function that actually needs to assign `createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames` create a `std::vector<char const *>` just for this task.